# Firestore how make query with one key but multiple values

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In tutorial there is an example when the value is single. It can be multiple keys but each key will have the single value. But I need to make the query and get results when I am showing multiple variants of value for one key.

For example, I need to get from collection only that users which ID's are in the list

Comment: Hi Boris! What is the purpose of that list? Which users are added to that list?

Comment: @AlexMamo i have added different collection for a feature where users can send each other friend request. So that list is a list of friends for a current user. And i need to get their objects from the table to inflate it to recycle which shows only friends requests for a current user

Comment: So you say that each user document has a collection of friends, right? Can you also show us please the database structure where the friends requests exist for a current user? Thanks!